# XPath issues with selecting an element which does NOT have an ancestor

Tags: xpath

I have the following simplified HTML of an issue I cannot resolve:

```html
<div class="some-ancestor">
  <div>
    <div class="target">I want this 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grand-parent">
    <div>
        <div class="target">I want this 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="some-other-relative">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="target">I don't want this 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">I don't want this 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <div class="target">I want this 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As implied in the HTML, I want to select the DIVs with the text "I want this" using these general rules:

- Rule 1: Must be a DIV with class "target"
- Rule 2: This DIV must NOT be a descendent of (the CSS) `.grand-parent .parent`
- Rule 3: With the Rule 2 above, this Xpath is auto-generated from any provided CSS so it can technically be any XPath snippet (but lets not worry about that for now).

So far I have the xpath for rule 1: `//div[@class='target']` which will return:

- I want this 1
- I want this 2
- I don't want this 1
- I don't want this 2
- I want this 3

And the following xpath for the equivalent of rule 2 will return:

```
//*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grand-parent ')]/descendant-or-self::*/*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' parent ')]
```

- I don't want this 1
- I don't want this 2

All good so far, we just need to combine them with a `not(ancestor::*)` in there right?

```
//div[
  @class='target'
  and not(
    ancestor::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grand-parent ')]/descendant-or-self::*/*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' parent ')]
  )
]
```

But this returns:

- I want this 1
- I want this 3

My issue here is the xpath above is ignoring "I want this 2" because it lives within `.grand-parent` but technically it should be selected as it resides outside of the `.parent` class.

I feel like there is some simple issue that I am missing regarding how the 2 parts of the xpath is put together, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div[@class='target' and not(../@class='parent') and not(../@class='grand-parent')]
```

If necessary, add the dots before the matching strings "parent" and "grand-parent". This expression checks only for parent elements and not the ancestors, because otherwise String 2 would be ignored, too.

Just to clarify: the parent `..` could also be written as `ancestor::*[1]`, hence the expression could also be (more complicated):

```
//div[@class='target' and not(ancestor::*[1]/@class='parent') and not(ancestor::*[1]/@class='grand-parent')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, both of your solutions do work, however...

My "Rule 3" above has the CSS to Xpath auto generated as the selector to ignore can be anything... so in this case I need to build an xpath where the following xpath CANNOT be changed:

`*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' grand-parent ')]/descendant-or-self::*/*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' parent ')]`

But I can take that xpath and place it anywhere within the main query.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe someone else can help you with that.

Comment: Translating arbitrary CSS to XPath is a very much bigger problem than your original question suggests.

Comment: I agree that converting CSS to Xpath is complex but I would be leveraging the Symfony CssSelectorConverter component in order to do so. So far it seems to do a good enough job converting simple CSS selectors to Xpath and we are ok working with its limitations.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html

It would be a easier to use the output of CssSelectorConverter and place it in a larger query as-is, than it would to modify the input or output of CssSelectorConverter to work with the larger query.